# Azure monitor integration with Microsoft teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

Can Azure monitor be integrated with Microsoft teams so that whenever an alert is triggered it should send a notification to the microsoft teams.

Comment: Is this a programming-related question?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the two ways you can do it,

1. Do it using [Webhooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/what-are-webhooks-and-connectors#:%7E:text=Webhooks%20and%20connectors%20are%20a%20simple%20way%20to,webhook%20and%20send%20a%20message%20to%20your%20service.). For this you can follow this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-incoming-webhook) to create incoming webhooks then you will need to [add an action group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/action-groups) in Azure Monitor that targets your webhook.
2. Second is do it with Logic apps, for this you can follow [Azure Monitor - Alert Notification via Teams](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/core-infrastructure-and-security/azure-monitor-alert-notification-via-teams/ba-p/2507676).